# record in my table not showing on my datatable in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I Have problem , the record cannot show up in my datatable, image:

[image: The Record Not Showing]

But in my table i have 2 record in date 2017-08-17

[image: My Table]

this is my code

> RekapController@show

```
 public function show($tanggal)
{
    $absen = Absen::where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y/%m/%d')"), 
    '=', $tanggal)
                ->get();
    return view('rekap.show')->with('data', $absen);
}
```

> index.blade.php (When i pass the variable)

```
<a href="{{ url('rekap', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value->created_at))) }}" 
class="btn btn-success">Lihat</a>
```

> show.blade.php (Datatable View)

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>No</th>
              <th>Nama</th>
              <th>Aksi</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($data as $index => $value)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ $value->siswa_id }}</td>
              <td>
                {!! Form::open(['route' => ['absen.destroy', $value->id], 
              'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
                  {{ Form::submit('Hapus', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) }}
                  <a href="{{ url('rekap', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value-
               >created_at))) }}" class="btn btn-success">Lihat</a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Print</a>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
          </table>
```

Thanks, i hope you can help me

Comment: What do you get in `return dd($absen)`; ?

Comment: where can i put your code?

Comment: try to use normal table see it works or not

Comment: In show method before `return view('rekap.show')....`

Comment: @AzzarioRazy please dd($absen) just before return statement in controller function, and please add that output

Comment: First debug your get query from show method, put `print_r($absen);` and let me know what happen?

Answer (score 0):

As i see in your index.blade.php, you have wrong date format.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value->created_at))
```

Your date format is in Y-m-d and your past to model used this format

```
DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y/%m/%d')
```

For better, you can try to change the format in your controller first. And your controller will looks like this.

```
public function show($tanggal) {
    $tempTanggal = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($tanggal));
    $absen       = Absen::where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y/%m/%d')"), '=', $tempTanggal)
                        ->get();
    return view('rekap.show')->with('data', $absen);
}
```